# C# sender для печати из RichTexBox

Tags: c#

Помогите с печатью. Мне нужно по нажатию на кнопку распечатать текст из RichTextBox. Вынес функционал в отдельный метод, чтобы можно было кроме кнопки использовать и пункт меню. Теперь не знаю, что передать туда в качестве sender. Сам метод:

```
            public void print()
    {

        using (PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog())
        {

            printDialog.ShowDialog();

            PrintDocument documentToPrint = new PrintDocument();
            printDialog.Document = documentToPrint;

            if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                StringReader reader = new StringReader(richTextBox.Text);
                documentToPrint.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler // тут нужен sender(documentToPrint.PrintPage());
                documentToPrint.Print();
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: Насколько помню, там ссылка на метод пишется. В этот метод `documentToPrint` автоматом прилетит в виде `sender`

Comment: @Александр пишет требуется имя метода, когда передаю просто documentToPrint

Comment: ну так да. Этот метод и надо указать

Comment: @Александр а какой метод "Этот"?))

Comment: `documentToPrint.PrintPage += (s, e) => MyPrintMethod();`